# PHP and Encoding problems

Tags: php

I got a php form which write fields in text files.
php file is utf8 and created files are utf8 too. (for persian language I need utf8)
problem:
when I open created file for example: post.txt in browser, I get something like:

```
ªÛŒØªØ± Ù…Ø·Ù„Ø¨:
Ù„ÛŒÙ†Ú© ØµÙØ­Ù‡:
Ø¢Ø¯Ø±Ø³ ØªØµÙˆÛŒØ
```

Code

```
<html dir="rtl">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>خبررسان</title>
<style type="text/css">
.form {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body class="form" style="margin: 0">
<?php
if($_POST['Submit'])

{

$title = $_POST['title'];

$link = $_POST['link'];

$image = $_POST['image'];

$post = $_POST['post'];


$postid = rand(0, 999999999);

//open the file and choose the mode

$fh = fopen("last.txt", "w");

fwrite($fh, $postid);

//close the file

fclose($fh);






//open the file and choose the mode

$fh = fopen("title.txt", "w");

fwrite($fh, $title);

//close the file

fclose($fh);

//open the file and choose the mode

$fh = fopen("link.txt", "w");

fwrite($fh, $link);

//close the file

fclose($fh);

//open the file and choose the mode

$fh = fopen("image.txt", "w");

fwrite($fh, $image);

//close the file

fclose($fh);

//open the file and choose the mode

$fh = fopen("post.txt", "w");

fwrite($fh, $post);

//close the file

fclose($fh);



header("Location:index.php");

}

else

{

print <<<ENDOFTXT

</style><form name="form1" method="post" action="index.php">

<table border="0" align="center">

<tr>

<td><span class="style5">تیتر مطلب:</span></td>

<td><input name="title" type="text" id="title" style="font-family: tahoma"></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td><span class="style5">لینک صفحه:</span></td>

<td><input name="link" type="text" id="link" value="" style="font-family: tahoma"></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td><span class="style5">آدرس تصویر:</span></td>

<td><input name="image" type="text" id="image" style="font-family: tahoma"></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td><span class="style5">مطلب:</span></td>

<td><textarea name="post" id="post" rows="5" cols="30" style="font-family: tahoma"></textarea></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td><input name="Submit" type="submit" class="style5" value="ارسال مطلب به مخاطبین من" style="font-family: tahoma"></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td colspan="2"><div align="center"></div></td>

</tr>

</table>

<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>

</form>

ENDOFTXT;

}
?>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is likely caused by incorrect charset headers sent by your webserver. 
If you are using an apache2 webserver, create a file called .htaccess and put: 
`AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`
into it.

This should tell apache to deliver a Content-Type:utf-8 header and fix your encoding problems.
Another solution would be to make a small HTML page that delivers the text file together with the meta-encoding header.